# How to create a facebook form post

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Can anybody please help me, I would like to put a post/form on Facebook that potential clients can interact with.

I dont know where to start and the paid options have alot of functionality that is not necessary.

The post will be basic, a photo with a question and 2 buttons. Then 2 answers, the 1 redirecting it to our page and the other to like our page.

If anyone is interested in helping me I would really appreciate this.

Comment: You can not do that with normal posts.

Comment: That I have realized but I know you can create a form and post it to your page and share that or boost it.

Comment: Well then do that ...?

Comment: Uhhm that is the whole point of the question. Can you maybe help

Comment: That's not a programming question, and as such off-topic. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section.

Comment: Misorude, please accept my apologies for this, I am looking for guidance. Please dont see my question as an attack on anybody just purely looking for some guidance of where to start. Facebook rarely respond and thus I am looking for somebody to point me in the right direction. I have been doing alot of research regarding this and I am not finding the right advice.